# When are Google Analytics cookies created?

Tags: python, cookies, google-analytics

I want know when the Google Analytics cookies are created? Is there a request to Google Analytics when we send a request to a site?
Also, where are these cookies stored? I don't find them with other cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are created when ga.js is executed. They are constantly modified with timestamps while visitors interact with the site and they are stored in visitor's browser. They are called __utma, __utmb, __utmz etc. If you don't see them maybe it's because of your browser settings. Here's the thorough guide: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/ga_cookies/index.html

Comment: Thanks. The AIM of my question is create these cookies with a Python request. I try to call ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js but GA cookies are not created. I think I have to send something else with this request?

Comment: Please describe the scenario you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This isn't actually correct. If you load `ga.js` on a page but don't make any GA function calls, no cookies will get set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer tools to see when the cookies are set. For instance:
[image]